# Can .Net 5 (Core) coexist on the same server with .Net 4.8 framework?

Tags: .net-5, .net-4.8

Can .Net 5 (Core) coexist on the same server with .Net 4.8 framework?

I can't seem to find a definitive answer on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not positive on whether or not you can do this on Azure, but I have it running locally on my Dev machine like this so, I think you probably can.

I will add that I ended up being able to modify my ADO.Net Transactions so that they don't escalate to Distributed Transactions, so now I am able to proceed with everything in .Net Core 5.

- Happy Hacking