# Can .NET 6 (Core) coexist on the same server with .NET 4.8 Framework?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

Can .NET 6 coexist on the same server with .NET 4.8 Framework? We have a .NET 3.1 application we want to update to .NET 6 but the same server also runs an application running on .NET Framework 4.8. However we can't update this application at this time. We don't want to install .NET 6 if we are going to blow up the .NET 4.8.

The closest answer I have found is [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67642204/can-net-5-core-coexist-on-the-same-server-with-net-4-8-framework) post, but it isn't definitive and .NET 6 is a different animal than .NET 5.

Comment: Just a comment, because I'm not 100% confident this is actually all correct. But my understanding so far is: Yes, it can, but not in the same web application and you will need to host your .Net 6 applications in IIS until you can get everything moved to .Net Core.

Comment: _" and .NET 6 is a different animal than .NET 5"_ - not that much. .NET 5 and .NET 6 are continuations of .NET Core  so if your server supports .NET Core 3.1 and .NET Framework 4.8  then there should be no problems with .NET 5/6.

Comment: Yes. .NET Framework has nothing to do with the new .NET. (speaking of installation/deployment)
.NET installes side-by-side while the "old" .NET Framework 4.8 was an in-place upgrade of the existing 4.x.

Comment: [_.NET 5 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5).  And [_.NET 6 delivers the final parts of the .NET unification plan that started with .NET 5_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6)

Comment: Yep, .NET 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 5 and 6 can all coexist on the same machine.

Comment: core and .net 4.8 are really different run-times, so they should be able to co-exist.  You can also bundle core with your app, so you wouldn't actually need to install .net6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, on my production server I am still running the main domain as .NET Framework 4.8, while I have created new subdomains running ASP.NET 6.

So just go ahead (of course you should still test locally, that other things don't interfere.

I should say, that I am running both on IIS.

One thing you should be aware of: If you want to run asp.net 6 in IIS 'inprocess' mode, then you need to create a new app pool for your new site, it can't share it with .Net Framework 4.8. If you can't do that, you must run in 'outofprocess' mode.

Comment: Thanks @Poul Bak, we upgraded the server to .net 6 and all is well. :)

Answer (score -3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server
According to this document, the answer is no.

Comment: That's not what that document says.  You can only have one version of .Net _Framework_ side by side with any number of .Net (Core) versions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30786202)